# Trigger create of one resource from the create of another in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

If a `post` has been made to `/user`, and my data model says that ever user must have a `group`, how, after successfully creating a `user`, would I trigger a new `group` to be created in sails.js? For that matter, how can I get into another controller from a lifecycle callback like `afterCreate` or via other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a controller inside a model, that would violate MVC pattern. You can create the group via

```
Group.create(obj)
```

or put  your creation logic inside a service.

Comment: I didn't actually want to create a group INSIDE the model, I just want to get into the `Group` controller. Are you saying `Group` (therefore `Group.create()`) would be available to me inside of the `User` model?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be confusing models and controllers, which is easy to do if you're new to Sails because of the *blueprints* functionality it provides.  That is to say: you don't need `GroupController` to create a `Group` model instances, and `GroupController.create` is *not* the correct way to create a new `Group` programatically.  `GroupController.create` is a method that's called automatically when you `POST` to `/group` because Sails has set up a "blueprint" create action at that location.

The correct way to create a `Group` programmatically is by using the `create` method of the `Group` model class, which is globally available in a Sails app.  So in your `afterCreate`, you could have:

```
afterCreate: function(values, cb) {
    Group.create({user: values.id}).exec(cb);
}
```

Note that the latest version of Sails (v0.10.0-rc5) supports nested creates, so if you've defined `User` and `Group` to be [associated](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelAssociations.md) with each other, you could just `POST` something like this to `/user`:

```
{
    name: "Joe Blow",
    age: 25,
    group: {
       name: "Joe's group"
    }
}
```

and the group will be created and associated with the user automatically.  If you `POST` an embedded `Group` with a primary key, it will search for an existing group with that key and link it to the new `User` instead of creating a new `Group`.

Comment: That's some really good info, thanks. I did have to accept the other answer as it did answer the question, though.